# How to lanuch Visual Studio code when installed through flatpak?

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, ide, flatpak

Running `flatpak list` shows:

```
Visual Studio Code                        com.visualstudio.code                    1.55.1-1617807524     stable    system
```

but how is that application launched?

*(The search results I've found are on how to install apps, rather than launch or run a specific app.)*

Answer (score 6):

When installed with Flatpak, you can launch VScode in the terminal by running:

```
flatpak run com.visualstudio.code
```

I recommend creating a permanent alias so that you only have to run `code` instead. To do this, add this line to the `.bashrc` file located in your home directory:

```
# User specific aliases and functions
alias code="flatpak run com.visualstudio.code"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tooling often expects that Visual Studio Code can be launched via the `code` command. Therefore an alias is not always sufficient.

In these cases you can create a bash script at `/usr/local/bin/code` with the following content and make it executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
flatpak run com.visualstudio.code "$@"
```

```bash
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/code
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/code
```